# What markdown formatter does RStudio use to convert to canonical markdown?

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, pandoc, formatter

I want to write a script to automatically convert `.qmd`, `.Rmd`, or `.md` files into the "canonical visual mode markdown" format that RStudio uses when writing Markdown in it. With that option selected, or if the Quarto YAML option `editor: markdown: canonical: true` is used, anytime you are editing and saving a Markdown document while in RStudio, it re-formats the Markdown into a standard format. This is *really* nice and useful when collaborating with others because then the Markdown is standardized. BUT! Not everyone uses RStudio, like for instance, if they make an edit to a GitHub repo directly through GitHub, the formatting doesn't happen. And I'd love to have a GitHub Action to run this automatically on the files.

So, I've been searching everywhere for how to convert Markdown into a "canonical" format. I've even dug deep into RStudio's source code to understand how they do it. Unfortunately, it's written in C++, TypeScript, and Java ([based on a search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Arstudio%2Frstudio+canonical&type=code)), something I don't have experience or knowledge of. I've also tried to directly use Pandoc, and it sorta works, but messes with Quarto's shortcodes and does other things I don't want. The code below is an example of my starting attempts on this, but it's not ideal.

```bash
# Shell script
reformat_markdown () {
  pandoc \
    --from markdown-smart+yaml_metadata_block+raw_attribute+blank_before_header \
    --standalone \
    --markdown-headings=atx \
    --wrap=auto \
    --columns=72 \
    --to markdown-smart+yaml_metadata_block+raw_attribute+blank_before_header \
    -o $1.new \
    $1
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? Are there easier ways of doing this?

Comment: I believe it's written in C++, not Typescript or Java

Comment: I believe it's rmarkdown, and the backend of that uses Pandoc? It sounds like you're asking 1. what libraries they use, and 2., what arguments they use to get a certain result

Comment: @Mark It's all those languages :P https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Arstudio%2Frstudio+canonical&type=code I've tried rmarkdown, but it still doesn't mimic it exactly.

Comment: try uninstalling pandoc and/or rmarkdown, and see if you can still create the "canonical visual mode markdown" format

Comment: it would also be helpful if you created steps for creating a thing in the  (so-called) "canonical visual mode markdown" format, so this question is reproducible

Comment: Have you looked into `quarto help` to see if `quarto render ...` or `quarto pandoc ...` or `quarto convert ...` come close to what you want?  _Generally_ these tools provided by RStudio / posit all work outside the IDE too. Or maybe I misunderstand and you want the format of the visual editor?  That may be tied to the IDE modifying it.

Comment: One thing with mark down is that there is not a fully definied standard, but I think it RStudio  uses CommonMark.  https://commonmark.org/       https://github.com/r-lib/commonmark